# How to read a list from appsettings.json and bind it in the mvc dropdownlistfor()

Tags: c#, html, json

```
"TransitAgency": [{
    "AgencyName": "abc"
    "AgencyId": 1
},
{
    "AgencyName": "cde"
    "AgencyId": 2
}]

enter code here
```

I have the above json format in app settings file; I have to display the above AgencyName in the dropdownlistfor of html view; How to achieve this?

Comment: Did you check the tutorials on [ASP.NET Core configuration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2)? How those values are read and used? The quick & dirty case is to [read the data from your controller or page directly](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#getvalue). Or you can use the [Options pattern](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to load the settings *and* register the data objects with dependency injection

Answer (score 0):

you can extract your array from your appsettings like this:

```
IConfigurationSection section = yourconfig.GetSection("TransitAgency");
var array = section.AsEnumerable();
```